# Ошибка в запросe (1054): Unknown column 'g.RomNo' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, select, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT `g.RomNo`
FROM GuestInfo AS g
INNER JOIN RoomInfo AS r 
ON r.RomNo = g.RomNo
WHERE  r.Type != '4'
AND g.goTime >= '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND  g.ComeTime <= '2019-09-01 00:00:00'
```

Ошибка в запросe (1054): Unknown column 'g.RomNo' in 'field list'

Но в обоих таблицах RomNo есть . И при SELECT * всё выводится

Comment: Значит нет. Или вы смотрите в другой базе. Покажите DDL таблиц

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , 1)  https://prnt.sc/p2ln7b 2) https://prnt.sc/p2lnly 3) Ошибка: https://prnt.sc/p2lnvp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас действительно нет поля

```
`g.RomNo`
```

у вас есть поле

```
g.`RomNo`
```

или

```
`g`.`RomNo`
g.RomNo
```

символы обратных кавычек подразумевают, что внутри находится цельный идентификатор